# Why doesn't it show me the confirmation dialog box that names the app and the permissions that I request = r2r?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, yelp

I'm looking at the instructions that come in the yelp documentation of the Authorization Code Workflow process:

Base URL: GET https://biz.yelp.com/oauth2/authorize

parameters:
client_id,
redirect_uri,
response_type,
scope,
state.

r2r - enables respond to review permission.

[https://biz.yelp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=https://www.locallity.com.mx/registration&response_type=code&scope=r2r&state=some_unique_string](https://biz.yelp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=https://www.locallity.com.mx/registration&response_type=code&scope=r2r&state=some_unique_string)

The question is the following: why doesn't the application authorize me, why doesn't it show me the confirmation dialog box that names the app and the permissions that I request = r2r?

The error is as follows:

> error= oauth_client_info_not_found&error_description=Specified client has not been set up with OAuth client info

[image]

I hope it shows me the permission confirmation window for the app.

[image]